# Is there a way to add a custom imaginary hostname for phpmyadmin in wamp server 2.4?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, host

I have a local site and remote site using wampserver. I have two connection files one for localhost with blank password and user "root", and the remote one obviously has a real hostname and password / user. I would like to set up my local wamp site so that the remote server details are used, as if I was working on remote server. Is there a way to create a user with hostname that imitates whats on the real server?

Basically I would like to access sql from php locally but with the real sql details that the host gave me. This will be an imaginary host as if it was real... sorry to confuse you!

Answer (score 1):

I generally use these settings in my configuration files. You can use them. It eliminates the need of manually editing configuration file every time you copy your files from localhost to remote server or vice-versa.

```
<?php

if ('127.0.0.1'==$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']){

    //Execute on local server
    define('DB_HOST','localhost');

} else {

    //Execute on remote server
    define('DB_HOST','server');

}
```

Hope they helps!

Comment: Thank you that is quite neat code, but I think that will directly connect to the host online, I don't want to do that. Instead I would like to create a virtual hostname and password which do not exist but still run on localhost.... so just the mysql hostname, user and password must be the same as online but there is no need to connect remotely. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? When working locally just leave your config.php file as your localhost settings, and then when you push to production/remote server, just update config.php to the relevant details?

You can change the WAMP server details, but I don't advise it, as it's just more work for future projects than the way above I've mentioned.

Comment: There are some reasons, I would like them to be identical to the server. I only need this for one folder/site in my wamp directory. I don't remember the exact reason, but I definately need to do it. :) Also the other files and the database I want everything to be the same as the server details... thanks for advice